# Play Framework + Angular Issue with JSON render on Page

Tags: angularjs, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have simple Scala Play Framework and Angular application. I tried to render JSON data on play's "xxx.scala.html" template but don't know what is the problem it is not rendering as expeted.

```
@main("Welcome to Play") {

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js">  </script>
<script>

    app.controller('NamesCtrl', function($scope) {
        // get names using AngularJS AJAX API
        $http.get('/getNames').success(function(data){
            $scope.names = data;
        });
    });

</script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-contoller="NamesCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat=" name in names">{{name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

}
```

My route entry

```
GET  /getNames controllers.HomeController.getNames
```

Scala Controller:

```
def getNames = Action {

    val names = List("Bob","Mike","John")
    Ok(Json.toJson(names)).as(JSON)

  }
```

When I am calling my page using url

> http://localhost:9000/getNames

I was getting response on page as below,

> ["Bob","Mike","John"]

Please can you explain what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks !!

Comment: `["Bob","Mike","John"]` is the expected JSON for such list.If you expect something else you need a custom `Writes`.

Comment: May be `.as("application/json")` ? Or just do not use `as()`

Comment: @MipH I tried with all the possible ways you mentioned in your comment but it is not working as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by *is not rendering*? Is it rendering something not properly or nothing at all? Is the AJAX request from Angular coming through the router?

Comment: try removing `.as(JSON)`

Comment: is not rendering? I mean it should render my JSON inside <ui><li> tag at each line but it is not. @BatteryAcid I tried to remove .as(JSON) and with JSON but still it is not working.

Comment: Is anything showing up on page? Post the output from angular.

Comment: @BatteryAcid I can see output on my page as ["Bob","Mike","John"], but not inside <ui><li> tag as expected.

Comment: Opening the URL in browser is a bit different from what Angular does. Is there any output from the angular call at all? You can try with `console.log(data)` in the `success` callback

Comment: @Anton, No I dont get anything on console.log. If you see my Play Controller, as I was returning (Ok(Json.toJson(names)).as(JSON)) JSON response how my application find which page to redirect?

Comment: Do you have INDEX page? I mean index action in Contoroller and Router in which you render your main template?
Something like `public Result index() { return ok(main.render()); }`

YOU HAVE to call http://localhost:9000/index in your browser and this page will do AJAX request to http://localhost:9000/getNames later...

Comment: Hi @MipH, I dont get how your below code will help in my case. If you looked at my above sample code when /getNames comes as my URL I want to rendered my page inside @main("Rendered JSON, "Bob","Mike","John" using html <ui><li> tag").

Comment: Where in java code do you define to rendering your xxx.scala.html (main) template?..

In your current example (based on the code you provided) you have only 1 action in you system "getNames" and it returns just json text. Your xxx.scala.html is not using at all.

Comment: I use java code for example. Do it in your own way in scala.

Comment: If you take yoour code from this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/21364555/2506303 it is not full! Just an relevant part of topic. Try to read some articles to understand the concept  i.e. http://matthiasnehlsen.com/blog/2013/06/23/angularjs-and-play-framework/

Comment: Hi @MipH, the same thing I used you have posted in your comment. I also dont know why you are looking for index(main) page in controller. I have used main page for common html and rendering using content in my "main" page based on URL change in browser. So I write a logic when /getNames URL comes I want to put json response in "main(content)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems in the code. The **correct** one is this:

```
@main("Welcome to Play") {

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.19/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="NamesCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('NamesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/getNames').success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.names = data;
    });
});
</script> 

}
```

What has changed:

- AngularJS 1.3.19 instead of 1.2.10
- AngularJS module - which is referenced in the `div`
- injected the `$http` service in the controller
- your ng was wrong - it should be `ng-controller` instead of `ng-contoller` (a typo I guess)

**The result** is what you would expect:

[image: Result]

Comment: I think it is working. I was doing something wrong in my code. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad that I could help :)